# Toggle checkbox list MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have three menus full of check boxes. I want to be able click each menu where the menu slides up and down. Is there a way to do this in jquery html below?

```
@foreach (string type in Model.ReportLists.Keys)
            { 

                <div id="flip"  class="type-container"  >

                    <h4>@type</h4>                   
                    <div  class="list-container" >
                        @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.ReportLists[type].PostedItems.CBItemIds,
                                  model => model.ReportLists[type].AvailableItems,
                                  item => Model.convertName(item.Name),
                                  item => item.Name,
                                  model => model.ReportLists[type].SelectedItems,
                                  MvcCheckBoxList.Model.Position.Vertical)
                    </div>

                    </div>


           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is a little unclear, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.type-container').each(function () {
        var $container = $(this);
        $container.find('h4').on('click', function () {
            $container.find('.list-container').slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
```

This would also work and may be slightly more efficient:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.type-container h4').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('.type-container').find('.list-container').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Interesting. Ran both through jsperf. Seems the second version is more efficient for intialization, but the first is more efficient at actually toggling the checkbox list. Since, initialization is a one-time cost, I'd recommend going with the first version.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the plain explanation!